# MySQL - Combining Records into Fields

Tags: mysql, sql

What i'm trying to do is query a table which holds custom data about a person and get it into fields, however i'm getting each individual field as a record in my return.

The current statement i'm using is

```
SELECT s.fname, s.lname, s.email, s.mobile, s.country, cf.name, ca.value FROM
standard AS s
INNER JOIN people AS p ON
(s.pid = p.pid)
INNER JOIN custom_answers AS ca ON
(ca.pid = p.pid)
INNER JOIN custom_fields AS cf ON
(cf.fieldid = ca.fieldid)
WHERE p.acctid = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
```

This is given a resultset of 22,000 rows, whereas i am only looking for 900 rows.

An example of the data output is

```
fname | lname | email | mobile | country | name     | value
tom   | smith | t@t   | 0412   | AU      | state    | Vic
tom   | smith | t@t   | 0412   | AU      | position | Dept Head
tom   | smith | t@t   | 0412   | AU      | guest    | John Smith
mick  | jones | m@j   | 0411   | AU      | postnom  | AOC
mick  | jones | m@j   | 0411   | AU      | state    | NSW
mick  | jones | m@j   | 0411   | AU      | postcode | 2000
```

whereas what i would like it to output is

```
fname | lname | email | mobile | country | state | position  | guest      | postnom | postcode
tom   | smith | t@t   | 0412   | AU      | Vic   | Dept Head | John Smith | null    | null
mick  | jones | m@j   | 0411   | AU      | NSW   | null      | null       | AOC     | 2000
```

what may or may not cause complication is that the amount of custom fields isn't the same for each person. some may have only a handful or custom fields, but some may have upwards of 30.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think the below structure will work. It's what I used to get school affiliations and belt ranks from tables separate from the users table.

EDITED: This is for a known number of associations and belt ranks, I'm not sure how you'd modify it for an unkown number of options, and adjusted for outer joins.

```
        SELECT test.tbl_user_accounts.*, t2.org_name as affil_one, t3.org_name as affil_two, t4.rank_name as rank_name
        FROM test.tbl_user_accounts 
        OUTER JOIN (test.tbl_organizations as t2) ON 
        (t2.org_id = test.tbl_user_accounts.affiliation_one)
        OUTER JOIN (test.tbl_organizations as t3) ON 
        (t3.org_id = test.tbl_user_accounts.affiliation_two)
        OUTER JOIN (test.tbl_ranks as t4) ON 
        (t4.id_rank = test.tbl_user_accounts.user_rank);
```

Comment: The answer needs to be uptdated to use outer joins because not every custom field is represented for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to apply a group by, by all non-aggregates, and this will create a roll-up... so applying a MAX() based on comparing the "cf.name" value to each element, you'll only get the value per "as" column... if no such record found, it will just remain blank (I've left empty spaces, but you could do NULL...

```
SELECT 
      s.fname, 
      s.lname, 
      s.email, 
      s.mobile, 
      s.country, 
      MAX( if( cf.name = 'state', ca.value, '          ' )) as State, 
      MAX( if( cf.name = 'position', ca.value, '          ' )) as Position, 
      MAX( if( cf.name = 'guest', ca.value, '          ' )) as Guest, 
      MAX( if( cf.name = 'postnom', ca.value, '          ' )) as PostNom, 
      MAX( if( cf.name = 'postcode', ca.value, '          ' )) as PostCode
   FROM
      standard AS s
         INNER JOIN people AS p 
            ON s.pid = p.pid
            INNER JOIN custom_answers AS ca
               ON p.pid = ca.pid 
               INNER JOIN custom_fields AS cf
                  ON ca.fieldid = cf1.fieldid 
   WHERE 
      p.acctid = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
   group by
      s.fname,
      s.lname,
      s.email,
      s.mobile,
      s.country
```